# When I run my html code does it jump after the sponsor section?

Tags: html

When I run my html code does it jump after the sponsor section? I haven't included the entirety but essentially it jumps from the navbar to the section after sponsors as soon as I scroll. Anyone got an idea why I assume its in that code somewhere but I've only just picked up on html and am just getting to grips with it, any help is much appreciated. I'm sure its something simple.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>The ESA Cup</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%7COpen+Sans:700,400%7CRaleway:400,800,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Images/ESA Star Logo White.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="css/library/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css-min/soccer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="dev-assets/preloader-default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="dev-assets/demo-switcher.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body class="esport-black">
    
    <div class="preloader-wrapper" id="preloader">
    <div class="motion-line dark-big"></div>
    <div class="motion-line yellow-big"></div>
    <div class="motion-line dark-small"></div>
    <div class="motion-line yellow-normal"></div>
    <div class="motion-line yellow-small1"></div>
    <div class="motion-line yellow-small2"></div>
</div>
    
    <!--ESPORT CHAMPIONSHIP HEADER BEGIN-->
<div class="esport-cmapionship-header">  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="contacts-wrap">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/ESA_Cup" class="facebook">
                            <img src="images/Images/twitter.png">
                            <span>Twitter</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@esa_cup" class="twitter">
                            <img src="images/images/tiktok.png">
                            <span>TikTok</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/esa_cup" class="google">
                            <img src="images/Images/twitch.png">
                            <span>Twitch</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://youtube.com/channel/UCGjCNbEF9CYqQxN7-LrDD6A" class="pinterest">
                            <img src="images/Images/yt.png">
                            <span>YouTube</span>
                        </a>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://discord.gg/K4NfuucwTN" class="pinterest">
                            <img src="images/Images/discord.png">
                            <span>Discord</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a class="logo" href="#">
                <img src="images/Images/ESA Logo Backgroundless White.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#landing-header" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="clear-header">
                <div id="landing-header" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#matches">matches</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#team">teams</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about">about</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact">contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!--ESPORT CHAMPIONSHIP SPONSORS BEGIN-->
<div class="esport-championship-sponsors">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 sponsors">
                <span>Our sponsors</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <img src="images/Images/logo_eagle_png_branca_1.png" alt="sponsor-image" style="height: 80px; width: 80px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4  text-center">
                <img src="images/Images/WHITE.png" alt="sponsor-image" style="height: 80px; width: 80px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4  text-center">
                <img src="images/Images/Untitled-1.png" alt="sponsor-image" style="height: 80px; width: 140px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried this, ill upload a video on whats happening real quick give me a sec.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GoRm2kA-4O34T4-lmBShrn_5aX_JENxr/view?usp=sharing) this is the video thanks for the quick response

Comment: Well if you watch the video you can see the sponsor part kinda gets skipped when I scroll, I want it changed so that no longer happens. Everything can stay in the same place id just like it to smoothly scroll over rather than jumping

Comment: Your problem is in the `CSS` file, please provide some `CSS styles` which related to your problem and make the `HTML code` a little bit less in the question

Comment: `code`.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

`code`.col-md-3 {
    float: left;
  }

`code`.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;

Comment: It seems to be realated to the top of the page, possibly even the navbar its self as when I added the padding/margin it still jumped at exactly the same place

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to your `CSS` file

```
*{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
```

**Edit**

if this solution did not solve your problem, So try to give your sponsors section `margin-top` or `Padding-top`

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, its really quite weird the only thing I can think of is somehow being related to the positioning but I cant quite get my head around it

Comment: Please check the **Edit**